# Libgdx android giving compiler error

Tags: android, libgdx

I am using libgdx framework for creating games on android.I configured the API's as per http://hrugames.com/installing-libgdx-in-eclipse-tutorial/ .But it worked only for that session of eclipse.After I restart eclipse or open it again, eclipse gives me a compile error saying:

"repackage that code. That is, move the classes in question into
your own package namespace. This means that they will never be in
conflict with core system classes. JarJar is a tool that may help
you in this endeavor. If you find that you cannot do this, then
that is an indication that the path you are on will ultimately
lead to pain, suffering, grief, and lamentation.

```
[2014-04-23 19:31:13 - GDX_GAMES] Dx 1 error; aborting
[2014-04-23 19:31:13 - GDX_GAMES] Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1"
```

The code does not compile.I have gone through many links but have not found any solution to it.Can anyone please help me?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Conversion+to+Dalvik+format+failed+with+error+1

Answer (score 0):

You use the old setup guide. Last versions of libgdx use Gradle. Follow this new official setup video tutorial: http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=3336